# Http 404 Not Found in MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am calling controls which has one parameter.

```
 http://localhost:49809/Import/QBData/test



[ActionName("QBData")]
        public bool getconnection(string id)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

...it is calling

But below control is not calling : always it is giving : Http 404 Not found...

I used this :

```
 http://localhost:49809/Import/Test/checking




 [ActionName("Test")]
        public bool Testing(string id)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

can any one tell me....why it is not calling...

Thanks !

Comment: Can you share your route config?

Comment: routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: @Havab, only that?! If so, it's no wonder it's blowing up :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a route that will match your action - this should match both.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Import", action = "QBData", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[1] { "Your.Namespace.Controllers" }
        );
```

Plus, why not make your action method named as you want rather than using the action name attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create an MVC project with a controller named Import and two action methods according to your code above.

```
    [ActionName("QBData")]
    public bool getconnection(string id)
    {
        return true;
    }

    [ActionName("Test")]
    public bool Testing(string id)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

In the file RouteConfig.cs I have the following code

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Everything works fine for me and I get a "true" as response in the browser for both URLs.

Make sure your routing is as specified above.